# SyntaxError: invalid syntax while using py2neo to create graph using fastapi

Tags: python, api, neo4j, fastapi, py2neo

I am trying to create a graph from the `post` request using fastapi but i was having `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` don't know where I was doing wrong.

```py
class usermodel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int
    weight: int
    nativety: str
    brith_type: str

class historymodel(BaseModel):
    data:bool

@app.post('/createuser')
async def createusernode(node:usermodel):
    user_node = Node("Person", name=node.name, age=node.age, weight=node.weight, nativety=node.nativety, birth_type=node.brith_type)
    return user_node

@app.get('/history')
async def historynode(node:historymodel):
    history_node = Node("History in Family", data=node.data)
    return history_node

family_history_relationship = Relationship(createusernode(node:usermodel),"Family History", historynode(node:historymodel))
graph.create(family_history_relationship)
```

`Error`

```
family_history_relationship = Relationship(createusernode(node:usermodel), "Family History", historynode(node:historymodel))
                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What is `node`? You seem to be using the type annotation syntax during a function call.

Comment: @quamrana Am i using type annotation syntax wrongly?. can you please correct me. What should i need to keep in the place of `node`

Comment: Well, it looks like you should just be calling the function like this: `createusernode(node)`, but what is `node`? This will be the next error.

Comment: ```@app.post("/items/")
async def create_item(item: Item):
    return item``` But here https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/?h=basemodel#import-pydantics-basemodel pydantic base model documentation their are using `item` the same way i was using `node`

Comment: Is this the complete code? To reproduce the error I would expect more.